# Batch Graph - count number of likes for numerous pages

Tags: facebook, batch-processing

I am currently getting the number of likes on individual pages by calling the below code, however I would like to get the likes for multiple pages at the same time.  Can't seem to find any documentation on if BATCH will allow this.

$like_result = file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://www.myadd.com/page1.php);
$like_array = json_decode($like_result, true);
$like_no = $like_array['shares'];

i.e. need the number of likes for:
ahttp://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://www.myadd.com/page1.php
ahttp://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://www.myadd.com/page2.php
ahttp://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://www.myadd.com/page3.php

Answer (score 6):

The [Graph API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#multirequests) explains how to use `ids` to select multiple objects simultaneously:

`/<API VERSION>/?ids=http://www.myadd.com/page1.php,http://www.myadd.com/page2.php,http://www.myadd.com/page3.php`

You could also use the [Batch Requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/) API (which has usage examples in the documentation) or a combination of the two (making batch calls of requests which ask for multiple objects)

Comment: great, `ids` parameter works! I have tested how many urls can I query per request and it is 2000 urls, If I test more eg. 2200 then facebook says "something went wrong"

Comment: That likely indicates a timeout or out of memory exception on Facebook's side; there's no 'specific' limit, but i'm a little surprised 2000 worked in a single call